# How to carry something with a shinuy

Tags: shabbat, how-to, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, shinuy-deviation

In certain instances, a person who must carry something with them on Shabbos is allowed to do so, but should try to do it by way of *shinuy* (שינוי), a way different from the norm, in order to minimize the amount and seriousness of prohibitions done*. (see, eg, שמירת שבת כהלכתה לב:נד, about bringing medicine that is critical [but not necessarily urgent])

Since that is so, what *shinuyim* can be done? I'm looking for practical suggestions on unusual ways to carry an object in public, not necessarily for a halachic discussion; the definition of *shinuy* is here.

**Every person should consult their own rabbis as to whether they are allowed/required to carry with a shinuy**, as well as to whether any of these answers count as a good *shinuy*, before implementing any of them.**

A good answer to this question will be practical, easy, concealable (who wants to look funny?), and not cause pain*** to the carrier.

---

* *For more discussion about the precise definition of "shinuy," see [What constitutes a shinui?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29083/5323)*
** *Assuming the situation isn't critical or urgent to saving life, in which case השואל הרי זה שופך דמים ([Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 328:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1596))*
*** *See my answer*

Comment: I've [asked and answered my own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but I'd love to hear other ideas about possible *shinuyim*!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen and done many *shinuyim* in my time.

The easiest that I could think of, if you're the black hat type (or heavily involved in Winterbash ;-), is to put something under your hat. There's usually plenty of room in there.

Another *shinuy* could be to put something in your sock, though if you'll be walking for a while, expect blisters on your ankle (that's what I did this week).
Also, you won't want to do this with things that you'll want to eat ( *I threw out that candies that I walked ~two miles with this week, when I got back home* :P)

Another thing you might try is to put something in between the waistband of your pants and your hip....though you should be careful that it doesn't fall out, which might cause problems with picking it up after it falls. ( *if it's needed, it's needed....but the point of the *shinuy* was exactly to avoid איסורי תורה, which you can get pretty easily by picking something up in רשות הרבים* )

If you're carrying something small like [Winkies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarties_(wafer_candy)) (also called "Rockets"), they'll sometimes fit inside the belt loops of a pair of pants. I've found that two to three of them will fit nicely in a belt loop together with a belt, and will not fall out easily.

For whatever it's worth to you, these *shinuyim* all passed by my rabbi.

Comment: Key in your mouth...

Comment: @DoubleAA You're more than welcome to post your own answer, though I'm not sure that this fits the OP's requirements of "easy" and "practical" ;-)

Comment: How far are you carrying it? Sometimes all you need is to cross the street and mouth is easier than taking off your shoes.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's true, certainly.

Comment: @DoubleAA Anything stopping you from posting your own answer? :P

Comment: I'm not sure that keeping things in your socks necessarily leads to blisters. Is that not the standard place to keep a dirk?

Comment: @TRiG I dunno about dirks, but [this](http://dexcom.com/dexcom-g4-platinum) certainly gave me a blister on my ankle this past Shabbos. It probably has a lot to do with how it's positioned, though.

Comment: @DoubleAA IIRC the _g'mara_ (and modern common sense also) says not to put a coin in your mouth because many people handle it. I assume the same would apply to (some) keys.

Comment: @msh210 If you know you'll be doing this just clean the key in advance. (I don't really think it's as dangerous as it may have been back then as we have tetanus shots, antibiotics, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

When I've needed to do this (which isn't often thankfully), it's usually a short distance inside the house, and for whatever reason it's also usually in the kitchen. Therefore I use what's available and carry the object with another object - I use salad tongs.

Comment: Is your kitchen outside? Also why are you allowed to carry the tongs?

Comment: I thought I worded the question to minimize its scope to *hotzaah*, but I guess not....the tags hint at my intent, but I should probably clarify exactly what I meant in the question body. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @DoubleAA Who sais anything about outside? There are many halachic authorities who hold that objects used for non-shabbat activities need to be moved with a shinui (if you're allowed to move them at all). See footnote 19 here: http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kli_SheMelachto_LeIsser

Comment: @Bachrach44 No one is talking about Muktza here. The question was about Hotzaah. (And that's not a shinui, per se, as much as kilachar yad.)

Comment: Honestly, what is ambiguous about "I'm looking for practical suggestions on unusual ways to carry an object in public, not necessarily for a halachic discussion"? cc @Shokhet

Comment: @DoubleAA is right -- the question *is* only about *hotzaah*, so this answer doesn't really cut it. I feel bad that this question sort of caused a flame war, but I really only meant to ask about הוצאה. Sorry, everyone!

Comment: @Shokhet Since this answer post has no upvotes, you can feel free to edit the question to remove whatever ambiguity the OP saw even if it invalidates this answer http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1231/759