# What are the opinions on carrying medicine/medical devices on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, medicine, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

Specifically, I'm curious about situations where it's not immediately apparent that it'll be necessary. For example: you don't know whether or not you'll need an epipen when you leave the house, but could you carry one with you anyway?

Comment: Arrange to have the epipen at your destination before Shabbos.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok While that would work for someone with a peanut allergy, I can't imagine it would be very useful for someone who's allergic to bee stings. There's also the question of people with asthma, who could need an inhaler at any moment.

Comment: Why do you have to leave the house at all? Also, is the location a public domain Deoraita or Derabanan?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50524/759

Answer (score 2):

[My rabbi told me](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2021/5323) that I should carry candy with me everywhere I go on Shabbos, out of concern for [hypoglycemia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoglycemia), which is a life-threatening condition. Hypoglycemia (also called "[low blood sugar](http://sixuntilme.com/wp/2013/11/07/low-blood-sugar-feels-like/)," or just a "low") is a function of [type 1 diabetes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diabetes_mellitus_type_1). A low can come almost without warning, even with the best control (*trust me, I know*).
If I'm going long-distance, I'll also carry a [blood glucose meter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucose_meter) and some other stuff I might need.

Where there is no eiruv, I [carry whatever I need with a *shinuy*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50524/5323); socks are useful, and should work for an Epipen also. As Avrohom Yitzchok [already pointed out](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53774/what-are-the-opinions-on-carrying-medicine-medical-devices-on-shabbat#comment142987_53774), arranging to have what you need wherever you go is a much better idea, provided you have enough medical devices to go around.
(*I have, at times, placed up to four meters in different buildings around a city I visited on Shabbos that didn't have an eiruv*)

It's [certainly](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) a [good idea](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) ask your own rabbi about your own particular situation, as to whether it will be necessary to carry stuff you need on Shabbos, and how that stuff should be carried.

Comment: While it may be obvious, it might be worth clarifying what disease puts you at risk for hypoglycemia and what the approximate risk of your getting it is.

Comment: @DoubleAA "approximate risk of your getting" ...T1D? Hypoglycemia?

Comment: risk of getting HG given that you have T1D. It could help indicate what level of risk justified the actions the rabbi took.

Comment: How's that, @DoubleAA?